# Simple Syntax error in bash

Tags: bash

This is the first time I am trying to write a bash script and I am getting seriously confused. I copied a simple script to parse a csv file and im getting an syntax error

```
test.bash: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
test.bash: line 8: `done '
```

I checked with an online syntax checker but did get nothing back. Could somebody here tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/input/file.cvs"
# Set "|" as the field separator using $IFS 
# and read line by line using while read combo 
while IFS='|' read -r f1
do
  echo "$f1 "
done
```

Comment: Should it not be `done < "$input"`

Comment: @anubhava That should wait, but not give SyxErr..

Comment: `I copied a simple script`. Definitely carriage returns ... again ...

Comment: I can not find a syntax error in the code you have posted. As others have pointed out, it's probably DOS newlines screwing things up for you.

Comment: Try running this command on the script as `sed -i s/\r// <script>` to remove the carriage returns present.

Comment: How do you start the script? If you run it with `sh ./test.bash` then the shebang would be ignored, and system shell (whatever it is) used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.  You just need to fetch the input from file by redirecting stdin, as said by @anubhava, and check that all end-of-lines are correct. You can do this with any text editor, if you don't feel experienced enough to use `sed`.

If it still doesn't work, put a `;` after the last command; it will stop execution of the current command at that point, so subsequent "dirty" EOL won't matter.

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/input/file.cvs"
# Set "|" as the field separator using $IFS 
# and read line by line using while read combo 
while IFS='|' read -r f1
do
  echo "$f1 "
done < $input ;
```